# Org mode org-schedule command

Tags: org-mode, calendar

How do I change the date when org brings up the Emacs calendar?  For example

1. `C-c C-s` (`org-schedule`)
2. Emacs calendar shows but the calendar motion commands `C-f`, `C-b` do not work.  Motion is in the minibuffer.

NOTE: I do not want to use the mouse to change the default date (today) placed into the minibuffer.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the section [The date/time prompt](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html) in the Org manual for various ways to specify dates in that prompt.